# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate

I am using hibernate 3.6.7 to do mapping from my classes to oracle tables.
I don't usually get this exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at com.mycompany.TransferFiles.TransferFilesToHadoop(TransferFiles.java:85)
    at com.mycompany.TransferJob.execute(TransferJob.java:25)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
 Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream
       at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.ClobTypeDescriptor.unwrap(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.ClobTypeDescriptor.unwrap(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$3$1.doBind(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2184)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2558)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2494)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2821)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at com.mycompany.HibernateUtil.getSession(HibernateUtil.java:36)
    at com.mycompany.BasicDaoImpl.saveOrUpdate(BasicDaoImpl.java:34)
    at com.mycompany.FileCopyRoutine.call(TransferFiles.java:297)
    at com.mycompany..FileCopyRoutine.call(TransferFiles.java:225)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
    at oracle.sql.CLOB.getDBAccess(CLOB.java:1196)
    at oracle.sql.CLOB.getCharacterStream(CLOB.java:278)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.SerializableClobProxy.invoke(SerializableClobProxy.java:74)
    at $Proxy2.getCharacterStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.ClobTypeDescriptor.unwrap(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:114)
```

When I call saveOrUpdate method.

Could anyone please give me some suggestion?

```
public static synchronized Session getSession() throws DBConnectionException{

    Session session = threadSession.get();

    if(session==null||!session.isOpen()||!session.isConnected()){
        if(sessionFactory==null||sessionFactory.isClosed())initHibernate();
        try{
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new DBConnectionException("Exception caught when trying to generate Hibernate session.");
        }
        threadSession.set(session);
    }
    if(session.isDirty()){
        session.flush();(36 line of HibernateUtil)
    }
    session.clear();
    return session;
}
```

I use it all for a long time.

now I am transferring file parallelly and then update database use saveOrUpdate method.Althrough there are many threads, I snychronized this part in my code.
I think we have connection to the database all the time, but it gives excpetion of closed connection.
Could anyone please give me some suggestion about this exception.What the problem should be?

I thought it could because of using saveOrUpdate, so I changed to merge, but it sames to have the same problem.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.ClobTypeDescriptor.unwrap(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.ClobTypeDescriptor.unwrap(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$3$1.doBind(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2184)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2558)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2494)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2821)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at mycompany.jobsrc.BasicDaoImpl.merge(BasicDaoImpl.java:52)
    at mycompany.FileCopyRoutine.call(TransferFiles.java:301)
    at mycompany.FileCopyRoutine.call(TransferFiles.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
    at oracle.sql.CLOB.getDBAccess(CLOB.java:1196)
    at oracle.sql.CLOB.getCharacterStream(CLOB.java:278)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.SerializableClobProxy.invoke(SerializableClobProxy.java:74)
    at $Proxy2.getCharacterStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.ClobTypeDescriptor.unwrap(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:114)
    ... 27 more
```

my merge code:

```
public void merge(T t) throws DBConnectionException{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.merge(t);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: one possible reason is that the "lob objects" isn't there. I have an experience with a similar problem but with PSQL, when the migration team didn't copy over the "blob objects" when we move to a new DB. Not sure if it applies for Oracle though

Answer (score 41):

Try adding **@Transactional** over the service method where you are trying to access lob field object. 
It worked for me.

Comment: Why does this work? auto-commit = false works as well so apparently Lob field must be read inside a transaction. But why?

Answer (score 7):

I believe I had this one before.

When a large object (CLOB, BLOB) is loaded from Oracle, it is returned as a reference to a stream. If the record is mapped to hibernate and the session is closed after the object is loaded (so the object becomes detached) the java field blob is mapped to is not containing the data yet; so when you're trying to save it back it cannot work with it because the clob/blob stream is gone.

For a start, try to keep loading and saving within the same session.

If I remember right, another workaround would be to "touch" the clob/bloc java field while the loading session is still open. Then the data will be read from the DB. But it is painfully inefficient (it is LOB for a reason, i.e. it is *big*).

Yet another option is to split the small data and lobs into two different tables, and load lobs only when needed.

Hope that helps you with the direction.

Comment: `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection` in the stacktrace implies otherwise...

Comment: Closed connection I believe relates to the connection that belonged to the session that was used to load the record. That one, yes, already closed when the object is attempted to get merged.

Comment: If it is occurring when trying to save or update it can't be related to lazy initialization right? The problem I think is that the save or update is getting a closed session...

Comment: BLOBs are lazy-initialized on driver level. Instead of data one gets a special proxy object -- a reference to BLOB. That object has a reference to connection. When you try to access the data (say, at merge) it will use the connection to retrieve the data. But the connection has been closed at that point already. So you're right, the problem is the closed session (and connection). Or so I believe.

Answer (score 2):

My pure guess is that you have some field that is very large, so it is mapped to sql lob. Mapping itself is incorrect, I suspect. But it only happens when you try to save entity with nonnull value. Try to save all your entities with nonnull fields in app one by one. This will isolate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In all probability I believe that this is due to `Session`
 mismanagement. But without reviewing a lot of code I cannot tell you what the exact problem of your current implementation is.

I believe `threadSession` is a ThreadLocal. Instead of doing this manually please use

`sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();`

and set thread in the hibernate config file.

And make your HibernateUtil is simple without all those checks. Personally I feel that those checks will cover up Session mismanagement and other errors... But well that may be just me...

Answer (score 2):

If using spring, adding the following application properties make it work for us:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit
```

Answer (score 0):

This might has to do something with JDBC drivers as discussed in this [thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28220/java-application-unable-to-access-blob-stream-in-oracle-after-upgrade-to-11g). Can you post the Oracle version and ojdbc jar version you using in project.

Answer (score 0):

As you use multithreading, my guess is that you could have some problem with transactions. It could be because of some transactions is somehow commited before you had done necessary changes to the object. Or you are trying to access object being saved from the different thread, that means the object is not in the scope of transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Add annotation to your lob field: `@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")`.
It works to me.

Answer (score -1):

Try remove `@Lob` in your property, if you are don't trying to access lob field object

Before:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
```

After:

```
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
```